# Comparing two sorted int arrays

Tags: java, arrays, comparison, int

I have millions of fixed-size (100) int arrays. Each array is sorted and has unique elements. For each array, I want to find all arrays which have 70% common elements. Right now I am getting around 1 million comparisons (using Arrays.binarySearch()) per second, which is too slow for us.

Can anyone recommend a better searching algorithm?

Comment: You might want to have a look at bloom filters.

Comment: So your result is a list of array pairs with at least 70 common elements?

Comment: Are the arrays static, once the comparison starts? Are are new arrays being generated all the time? In other words, is it possible to convert/preprocess the arrays into some other data structure to optimize the search?

Comment: Yeah, result is a list of array pairs with at least 70 common elements.

Comment: Yeah, Arrays are static and numbers of arrays as also fixed.

Comment: Also, how many matches are you expecting? Are the ints roughly evenly distributed? I'm asking this because if there aren't many matches, then exclusion heuristics might help.

Comment: I am expecting around 10% matches based on my initial data set.

Comment: Not have much idea about bloom filters. Let me get some info about it. thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Using `Arrays.binarySearch()` makes no sense here for me. For comparing two arrays, you just need to go through both of them in parallel and count the common elements on the fly. What I mean is very similar to mergesort.

Comment: With 10% matches and millions of arrays you get over 1e6 * 1e6 * 0.1 = 1e11 matching pairs, this is a bit too much, isn't it? I suppose I misunderstood something. Could you clarify this? One more question: What range do the ints lie in?

Comment: Yeah, Matching pair is huge. ints are all over the place. no particular range. Right  now, we are doing this comparison in map reduce framework. But even with 10 or so machines, its difficult to get process done within reasonable time frame. SO i am tryng to optimize comparision on single machine before we move to distributed framework.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking that this is exactly the sort of thing that might be written in assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the job (provided that the arrays are sorted and contain unique elements):

```
public static boolean atLeastNMatchingElements(final int n,
    final int[] arr1,
    final int[] arr2){

    /* check assumptions */
    assert (arr1.length == arr2.length);

    final int arrLength = arr2.length;

    { /* optimization */
        final int maxOffset = Math.max(arrLength - n, 0);
        if(arr1[maxOffset] < arr2[0] || arr2[maxOffset] < arr1[0]){
            return false;
        }
    }

    int arr2Offset = 0;
    int matches = 0;

    /* declare variables only once, outside loop */
    int compResult; int candidate;

    for(int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++){
        candidate = arr1[i];
        while(arr2Offset < arrLength - 1){
            compResult = arr2[arr2Offset] - candidate;
            if(compResult > 0){
                break;
            } else{
                arr2Offset++;
                if(compResult == 0){
                    matches++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(matches == n){
            return true;
        }
        /* optimization */
        else if(matches < n - (arrLength - arr2Offset)){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
public static void main(final String[] args){
    final int[] arr1 = new int[100];
    final int[] arr2 = new int[100];
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if(i % 10 == 0){
            x++;
        }
        if(i % 12 == 0){
            y++;
        }
        arr1[i] = x;
        arr2[i] = y;
        x++;
        y++;
    }
    System.out.println(atLeastNMatchingElements(70, arr1, arr2));
    System.out.println(atLeastNMatchingElements(95, arr1, arr2));
}
```

**Output:**

> true
>   false

### Premature Optimizations™

I have now tried to optimize the above code. Please check whether the code blocks marked as

```
/* optimization */
```

make a noticeable difference. After optimization, I would refactor the code to get it down to one or two return statements.

Comment: That's nice. It could be generalized for working with many arrays at once, and probably it would be faster than working pairwise only. However, I think, some better idea is needed, still.

Comment: @ashish I have added some minor optimizations, see my update @maaartinus I agree some better idea is needed

Comment: Does not seems to make much diff. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @ashish though so. int[] arrays are very fast, so every 'optimization' might actually slow things down

Comment: @sean  This seems to be best possible answer for me right now. Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 3):

You could try a merge sort ignoring duplicates. This is an O(n) operation for sorted arrays. If the two arrays have 70% elements in common the resulting collection will have 130 or less unique ints.  In your case you don't need the result so you can just count the number of unique entries and stop as soon as you reach 131 or the end of both arrays.

EDIT (2)  The following code can do ~176 billion comparisions in about 47 seconds using 4 cores.  Making the code multi-threaded with 4 cours was only 70% faster.

Using BitSet only works if the range of int values is fairly small. Otherwise you have to compare the int[] (I have left the code in should you need it)

> Peformed 176,467,034,428 comparisons in 47.712 seconds and found 444,888 matches

```
public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException {
    int length = 100;
    int[][] ints = generateArrays(50000, length);
    final BitSet[] bitSets = new BitSet[ints.length];
    for(int i=0;i<ints.length;i++) {
        int[] ia = ints[i];
        BitSet bs = new BitSet(ia[ia.length-1]);
        for (int i1 : ia)
            bs.set(i1);
        bitSets[i] = bs;
    }

    final AtomicInteger matches = new AtomicInteger();
    final AtomicLong comparisons = new AtomicLong();
    int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);

    long start = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < bitSets.length - 1; i++) {
        final int finalI = i;
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int j = finalI + 1; j < bitSets.length; j++) {
                    int compare = compare(bitSets[finalI], bitSets[j]);
                    if (compare <= 130)
                        matches.incrementAndGet();
                    comparisons.addAndGet(compare);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    executorService.shutdown();
    executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.printf("Peformed %,d comparisons in %.3f seconds and found %,d matches %n",comparisons.longValue(),time/1e9, matches.intValue());
}

private static int[][] generateArrays(int count, int length) {
    List<Integer> rawValues = new ArrayList<Integer>(170);
    for (int i = 0; i < 170; i++)
        rawValues.add(i);

    int[][] ints = new int[count][length];
    Random rand = new Random(1);
    for (int[] ia : ints) {
        Collections.shuffle(rawValues, rand);
        for (int i = 0; i < ia.length; i++)
            ia[i] = (int) (int) rawValues.get(i);
        Arrays.sort(ia);
    }
    return ints;
}

private static int compare(int[] ia, int[] ja) {
    int count = 0;
    int i=0,j=0;
    while(i<ia.length && j<ja.length) {
        int iv = ia[i];
        int jv = ja[j];
        if (iv < jv) {
            i++;
        } else if (iv > jv) {
            j++;
        } else {
            count++; // duplicate
            i++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return ia.length + ja.length - count;
}
private static int compare(BitSet ia, BitSet ja) {
    BitSet both = new BitSet(Math.max(ia.length(), ja.length()));
    both.or(ia);
    both.or(ja);
    return both.cardinality();
}
```

Comment: This may speed up the comparision (which was `O(1)` anyway because of equal sized arrays), but I think, the performance killer is the huge number of comparisions itself (`O(n^2)` if I got it right with `n >> 1,000,000`)

Comment: Yeah, n^2 comparison is the issue here. This will be distributed on more than one machine. For now, i am trying to figure out best possible way to compare. I am pretty sure that its not possible with one machine to achieve what i am looking for.

Comment: @ashish, as long as the comparison is cheap you can do 1 million comparison in under a second.  How many arrays do you have to compare?

Comment: One core of a 3 GHz processor can do a billion int comparisons a second. ;) esp reading an array sequentially so data is loaded into cache efficiently.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey you are right. BitSet is not useful here in mycase as range of int is all over the place. Thanks.

Comment: The int[] compare does 1 billion every two seconds.  This code should give you a framework to run on one machine or many.

Answer (score 3):

There are two quick optimisations you can make.

If array A's start element is greater than B's end element, they trivially can't have common elements.

They other one is a triangle inequality-like thing:

```
f(B,C) <= 100 - |f(A,B)-f(A,C)|
```

The reason for this is that (assuming `f(A,B) > f(A,C)`) there are at least `f(A,B) - f(A,C)` elements that are in both A and B but not in C. Which means that they can't be common elements of B and C.